# How to effectively work with leksah?

Tags: haskell, leksah

How can I effectively work with the leksah haskell IDE?
For a start, I am very thankful for all the work that the leksah people put in. It's great!

However, I have trouble working effectively in leksah.

```
mymain :: IO ()
mymain = do
    myData <- getMyData
    ...
    ...
```

How can I show the type of some variable in a do-expression, like `myData`? When I right click on it and then go to type, the error message gets `<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: 'myData'`. Also after I do something with ghci in leksah, build (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) no longer compiles my project but suddenly does something else.

How can I effectively use leksah in general and especially concerning ghci in leksah (like display a type of something that is not toplevel but nested)? What are the top 5 things you would suggest?

Comment: I, like you, found using leksah for Haskell enormously confusing. I know this doesn't answer your question but I would recommend using EclipseFP with the haskell plug-in (many tutorials are available online).

Comment: thanks for the comment! However I would like a solution using leksah and not switch to a different IDE. I am quite happy with most that leksah has to offer, even tough it is sometime difficult to use (bugs, lack of documentation). Also I want to support leksah by using it!

Comment: please answer, the open bounty will go to anyone who answers and is gone otherwise!

Comment: bounty goes to anyone who answers in the next 23h hours (it's gone otherwise...)

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow - it would be ok if it was just asking about how to show types and nothing more.

Comment: It's simply a raw product and has lots of loose ends compared to other editors.  If that's not good enough--fortunately it's open source.  So, grab the code and add the features you want.